# Bind list or array to form in Thymleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

On my website I have a few checkboxes each of them contains id in `value` attribute. After submitting form I'd like to have a list containing ids of checked checkboxes to be passed to the controller. That's how I want to make new page comparing n products.

Controller can accept `List<Long>` or `long[]`. That's what I have for now:

**HTML:**

```html
<form th:action="@{/comparison}" th:object="${productsComparison}" target="_blank" method="post">
<table>
  <tr data-th-each="item, iter : ${items.item}">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" th:name="|productsComparison.ids[${iter.index}]|" th:value="${item.id}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've added to my controller `List<Long>` wrapped in `ProductComparison` with appropriate getters and setters. After submitting form list is always **null**.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/productsPage")
public String showProducts(Model model) {
    ProductsComparison productsComparison = new ProductsComparison();
    model.addAttribute("productsComparison", productsComparison);
}

@RequestMapping("/comparison")
public String compareProducts(@ModelAttribute ProductsComparison productsComparison) {
    System.out.println("List: " + productComparison.getIds());
    // Always shows null
    return "comparison";
}
```

```
public class ProductsComparison {
    private List<Long> ids;
    // Getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Can you show controller code?

Comment: Does this really work? ${items.item}

Comment: @SAP Yes it does. With `${items.item}` I'm extracting list of items, it's irrelevant  to the problem because I can see value attribute in the source code correctly. I guess that the problem is related to `th:name`.

Comment: Off-Topic: You shlould not mix `data-th-*` and `th:*` (both do the same). That's confusing.

Comment: Try `th:name="|ids[${iter.index}]|"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found solution. Instead of `th:name` I had to use `th:field`.

```
th:field="*{ids[__${iter.index}__]}"
```

Because it's field I didn't have to specify object `productsComparison` before ids. `ids` field is `List<String>`.

To be honest I have no idea what underscores do, I will be glad if someone could explain.

Answer (score 3):

The underscores `__` are ThymeLeaf's syntax for a preprocessing expression. Or in layman's terms, the stuff inside of the underscores are processed before the rest of the expression.

This is important because your expression is using an array, and the `${iter.index}` portion of it gives the array index.

If you are curious or if anyone else stumbles upon this. `th:name` is no different than the html attribute `name`. The ThymeLeaf engine will just shove a name attribute into the html entity or overwrite the old one. ThymeLeaf has a ton of properties like [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes). `th:field` is a totally different beast though. It is what tells ThymeLeaf to bind the input of your form to the back forming bean or your model attribute, `th:object="${productsComparison}"`. So with the expression `th:field="*{ids[__${iter.index}__]}"`, Thymeleaf is going to call `productsComparison.getIds[0]` and the corresponding setter.

Note about `th:name` if you are submitting with Javascript of any kind, you probably want to use this. Most likely you are serializing your form, and the JSON created by this method call will use the name property.

If you want to know more about ThymeLeaf preprocessing expressions, there is a bit in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields) about it.